# Arguments to res_similarity() function

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am using resnik similarity algorithm to find similarity between two synsets and I am using it in the following way in python:

```
def get_maximum(synset1,synset2):
    maxSim = None
    for s1 in synset1:
          for s2 in synset2:
               sim = s1.res_similarity(s2)
               if maxSim == None or maxSim < sim:
                     maxSim = sim
    return maxSim
```

Here I am getting following error:

```
Typeerror: res_similarity() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Can somebody tell me which one is third argument?

Comment: `es_similarity` from instance `s1` needs 2 arguments (without self) you are passing only 1 - s2 show us the code for res_similarity it will be much easier.

Comment: @ Kobi K: thanks for reply. I got the solution and the third argument is IC for which i have added wordnet_ic package from nltk,corpus

Comment: NP, I've added some more info at the answer, if it solves your question you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeerror from docs:

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of
>   inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details
>   about the type mismatch.

At you case you have a function names `res_similarity()` that need to take 2 arguments.

The reason you see 3 and 2 given is because it has also `self`.

For example `res_similarity(self, arg1, arg2)` you are passing only 1 parameter - `s2`

You need to pass one more parameter to this method